# Where did the easy_install and pip packages go?

Tags: package-management, python, software-installation

I wrote a Bash script which automates the installation of an application based on [ERPNext](https://erpnext.com/) 3.6.1* on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS laptop.

Part of the script installs required dependencies using `apt-get install`, which include `pip` and `easy_install`. The script worked fine a couple days ago, but now when I try to run it, this step fails with the following error messages from `apt-get` in the terminal:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package easy_install
E: Unable to locate package pip
```

I cannot find these packages in the Ubuntu Software Center either, although I do still have the commands installed on my system (see below) and a search for either in the Ubuntu Software Center returns the installed package `python-pip` as the first result.

I also ran the following to try and figure out which package owns the installed commands:

```
christopher@SkyTemple:~$ whereis easy_install
easy_install: /usr/local/bin/easy_install
christopher@SkyTemple:~$ dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/easy_install
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/easy_install
christopher@SkyTemple:~$ whereis pip
pip: /usr/bin/pip /usr/bin/X11/pip /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz
christopher@SkyTemple:~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/pip
python-pip: /usr/bin/pip
```

Did `pip` and `easy_install` recently roll into `python-pip`? Or are they altogether gone now? I need to know how I should update my script, if needed.

*<sub>* Out of date, I know, but this is what my employer has supplied from our contractor, so I need to work with it.</sub>*

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/easy_install` indicates this is a local installation of the file, and the file is not managed by `dpkg`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pip` has always been in package `python-pip` and `easy_install` in `python-setuptools`.

Ubuntu 10.04 has a package `pip` but that's a different program ("Perl Installation Program").

You seem to have installed your own version of setuptools in `/usr/local/`.

Comment: The `/usr/local/` install might be due to an ERPNext-supplied script called further down in my script. The only thing I'm still wondering is why `sudo apt-get install pip easy_install` worked before with no problems if those packages didn't exist in the first place.